# Изменение видимой области в google maps

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps-api, google-maps

Суть задачи такова: У меня есть маркеры, в разных городах России, так же у меня есть выпадашка, в которой даны города и определенные точки в этих городах (предположим остановка), и при выборе из выпадашки города, например Москва, нужно чтобы карта переключалась на нужный маркер (то есть изначально видимой областью была вся Россия, теперь же будет определенный маркер). Как это возможно реализовать? На данный момент есть только сама карта и маркеры.

```
 var neighborhoods = [
    {lat: 56.832648,  lng: 60.5800283},
    {lat: 54.785281,  lng: 56.0308721},

  ];

  var markers = [];
  var map;

  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 3,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      center: {lat: 62.3371518, lng: 90.2720958},
    });
  }`
```

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так, как здесь

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple,

только событием будет не click, а выбор из выпадашки.